# Cloud Functions triggered by Cloud PubSub duplicate messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm experimenting with using Cloud Functions as async background worker triggered by PubSub and doing a bit longer work (in order of minutes). 
The complete code is here https://github.com/zdenulo/cloud-functions-pubsub

My prototype inserts data into BigQuery and waits for a few minutes (to mimic longer task).
I am publishing 100 messages to PubSub topic (with 1 second interval).

It's emphasized that PubSub can deliver more than once the same message, but I was surprised that from 10 to 40 out of 100 are duplicated. Response time for CF was 5, 6, 7 minutes. For 4 minutes response, I didn't notice duplicates.
I've done multiple tests for the same time intervals. Time difference between receiving first and second message ranges from ~30 to ~600 seconds.

In documentation https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting is mentioned "Cloud Pub/Sub can send duplicate messages. For instance, when you do not acknowledge a message before its acknowledgement deadline has expired, Cloud Pub/Sub resends the message." For Cloud Functions Subscription, acknowledge deadline is 600 seconds (10 minutes), so based on my understanding that shouldn't be the reason.

Maybe the test case I have is specific or maybe there is something else.
I would be grateful for advice on how to handle such a situation and if this is normal or how to do it to prevent duplicates (excluding Dataflow).

Comment: Cloud Functions can duplicate events as well, for any kind of trigger, so your functions really should expect to receive duplicates by being idempotent.

Comment: All triggers **except** HTTP trigger. As [explained in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees), HTTP functions are invoked at _most_ once, while background functions (pubsub or any other trigger) are invoked at _least_ once.

Comment: thanks for the comments and clarification.

Comment: There is a good comment here - https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq - titled "How do I detect duplicate messages?".   I think a common technique is to use a cheap global data store (redis/memcache) and save the message_id of each message that is processed.  Before you process a new message, check that you haven't seen it before in the cache.

Comment: thanks, @Kolban. Redis/memcache approach should work, but for non-frequent, small usage, that could be a bit overkill. It always depends on the use case I guess. I'm just surprised that I'm seeing a high percentage of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue impacting Cloud Functions deployed before January 2019 that causes an increased rate of duplicate triggers for functions that take more than 5 minutes to run. Please try deleting and re-deploying your function to resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks for the comment. The function was deployed a few days ago. Anyway since Cloud Tasks supports now Cloud Functions as tasks workers, this approach is more suitable for my case.