# Is there a way to identify duplicate notification message for Pub/Sub in gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to gcp and not sure if there is a way to do this so I need some suggestions.

I currently have a system in which for a topic I receive notifications when a new object is created in some folder. After this I have a cloud function which will get triggered when a new notification is generated in that topic. This function gets data from object and changes multiple object in cloud storage.

The issue is I am getting multiple notifications for same object and this will create multiple instances of cloud functions. This is not feasible for my system. I cannot have more than one instance of cloud function operating on same object as it will be changing other object and will create race conditions.

I am looking for a way to get just one notification for one object/ acknowledge the topic that the notification is received don't send it again. The other option is to trigger directly from object storage using cloud storage trigger but the problem is that this will trigger for all objects in bucket rather than just for objects in specific folder.

I am open to all ideas.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @norbjd is right when you have to dedicate pubsub message on message id.

But, I understand that isn't your case. You want to dedicate on the content, more precisely on the attributes `bucketId` and `objectId` as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#format). When this pair it's still processing, you don't want to start a new process on the same object.

If I'm right, the previous answer won't help, except a tip at the end with redis/memorystore (like memcache but not limited to appengine). In fact, you have you deduplicate by yourselves. You have to store somewhere a semaphore token for saying: "this object is processing". At the beginning off the function you get it, check if active or not. If not, write that your function is processing it. Are then end off there function, delete it.

You can do this with several component. If you have a huge number of objects, use memorystore for performance. If you have a reasonable number of event per day (less than 30000), choose for Firestore/datastore.
Special mention if you already have a cloud SQL instance, you can also use it (by the way, you won't pay more!)

Final tips. It's possible that 2 functions start in same time, check the token in the same time and write in the same time. For preventing this, I recommend you to write, in addition of the object, the message id, and to follow this process:

- Get the token
- Check if exist, if yes, exit function
- If not write the object and messageid
- Get the token. If exist and the messageid if different of the current messageid of the function, exit -> concurrent write, prevented
- If the messageid if the same, continue
  ...
- End of process, delete the token.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pub/Sub trigger, the responsibility of deduplicating messages falls on your application because Pub/Sub have an [at-least-once behavior](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery) :

> Typically, Cloud Pub/Sub delivers each message once and in the order in which it was published. However, messages may sometimes be delivered out of order or more than once. In general, accommodating more-than-once delivery requires your subscriber to be idempotent when processing messages.

However, from the same documentation, [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) is presented as an option to deduplicate messages :

> You can achieve exactly once processing of Cloud Pub/Sub message streams using Cloud Dataflow PubsubIO. PubsubIO de-duplicates messages on custom message identifiers or those assigned by Cloud Pub/Sub.

You could create a Dataflow job deduplicating your Pub/Sub messages and triggering directly your Cloud Function (via HTTP for example, because sending the deduplicated message on another Pub/Sub topic will lead to the same at-least-once behavior). Downside here is that it adds overhead to your application (Dataflow job + Cloud Function).

Using Cloud Storage trigger could be an idea; however, from the documentation about [Event delivery mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#event_delivery_mechanism), it looks like behind the scenes, the Cloud Storage trigger is delivered through Pub/Sub, potentially leading to the same issues (I don't know if the deduplication is made in this case, docs are unclear). If you choose to use this, as you wrote, your function will be triggered at each object update in your bucket, so you will need to filter the events directly at the beginning of your Cloud Function to check if there is something to do (the updated object is interesting or not).

From my experience, I suggest you to keep the Pub/Sub trigger (since your upstream application already notifies when an object is created in some folder) and deal with duplicates inside your Cloud Function. Making your Cloud Function idempotent is always a good idea in all cases, and duplicate messages are not so common (I can't find any number though). To handle the duplicates, check [@Kolban's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193898/cloud-functions-triggered-by-cloud-pubsub-duplicate-messages#comment99016192_56193898) on this Stackoverflow question ([Cloud Functions triggered by Cloud PubSub duplicate messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193898/cloud-functions-triggered-by-cloud-pubsub-duplicate-messages)) :

> I think a common technique is to use a cheap global data store (redis/memcache) and save the message_id of each message that is processed. Before you process a new message, check that you haven't seen it before in the cache.

If you really can't allow any duplicate in your Cloud Function, then the only way is to use the HTTP trigger, the only trigger ensuring [*at most once* behavior](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees).